# Determine if DVD is DVD-R or DVD+R

Tags: dvd, cd, media

Is there an Ubuntu/Linux command or app that will determine if a DVD is a DVD-R or DVD+R (DVD-RW or DVD+RW etc.)? Or that will display all the Media Identification Code information of a disc, including the aforementioned types?

Looking to find that information for DVDs that are blanks as well as already burned, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be automatically mounted when inserted and tell you what it is when you are in your file manager.